# C# How do I use dictionaries and lists with user input?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am building on a project that I already created. This is my first attempt at using dictionaries/lists. This a very broad question, as the book I have does not cover using dictionaries at all, and I am having trouble finding examples of dictionaries with user input online. I have made a program using a multidimensional array that asks the user for a number of students and a number of exams, then has the user enter scores for each exam, and outputs each students average grade based on their exam scores. I now want to achieve the same thing, only using dictionaries and lists instead of arrays. I don't even know where to begin. Can anyone explain how this would work? Here is the code I already have created, though it probably will not be helpful at all:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int TotalStudents = 0;
        int TotalGrades = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of students: ");
        TotalStudents = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of exams: ");
        TotalGrades = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[,] scoresArray = new int[TotalStudents, TotalGrades];

        for (int r = 0; r < TotalStudents; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < TotalGrades; c++)
            {
            Console.Write("Please enter exam score {0} for student {1}: ", c + 1, r + 1);
                scoresArray[r, c] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        for (int r = 0; r < scoresArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            int studentSum = 0;
            int testCount = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c < scoresArray.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                studentSum += scoresArray[r, c];
                testCount++;
            }
            string gradeLetter = "";
            double average = studentSum / testCount;
            Console.WriteLine("\nStudent " + (r + 1).ToString() + " Average Score: " + average.ToString());

            if (average >= 90)
            {
                gradeLetter = "A";
            }
            else if (average >= 80 && average < 90)
            {
                gradeLetter = "B";
            }
            else if (average >= 70 && average < 80)
            {
                gradeLetter = "C";
            }
            else if (average >= 60 && average < 70)
            {
                gradeLetter = "D";
            }
            else
            {
                gradeLetter = "F";
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Student " + (r + 1).ToString() + " will recieve a(n) " + gradeLetter + " in the class.\n");
        }
        Console.Write("\nPress the [ENTER] key to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Create a dictionary that maps a *student* to a *list of scores* .

Comment: And this code doesn't compile. Please post only the necessary complete code that compiles.

Comment: `Dictionary<string,List<double>>` where string is the student ID and `List<double>` is the test scores.  The string value is the key and the value is the list.

Comment: Or create a Student class that contains an ID and a list of test scores and average.  Then you can do `Dictionary<string,Student>`.  This gives you more flexibility in the way you handle properties.

Comment: On a side note, there's a really weird line of code that seems wrong: `TotalGrades = Convert.Topublic`.

Comment: @DevinLiu I think it's `Convert.ToInt32()` and `public static` merged to create a monster the like of which the world has never seen before.

Comment: And at the beginning of the class there is a bunch of code that should be contained in a method that isn't...

Comment: Sorry about the copy/paste error in my original code- was trying to skip some notes I had made while fooling around with dictionaries and ended up butchering my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are a wonderful tool!  I tried to use your original logic, but at times, I had to go another way.  Also, I kept getting lost with the "c" and "r" index variables.  I prefer longer names for indices.

```
//Let's create a gradeTranslator dictionary.
// As the grades follow the simple divisions along averages divisible by 10,
// we can just use the first digit of the average to determine the grade.


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool useSampleData = true;
            Dictionary<string, List<double>> gradeBook = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
            Dictionary<int, string> gradeTranslator = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                gradeTranslator.Add(i, "F");
            }
            gradeTranslator.Add(6, "D");
            gradeTranslator.Add(7, "C");
            gradeTranslator.Add(8, "B");
            gradeTranslator.Add(9, "A");
            gradeTranslator.Add(10, "A");

            int TotalStudents, TotalGrades;

            // For testing purposes, it is a lot easier to start with some
            // sample data. So, I created a query to see if the user wants 
            // to use sample data or to provide her own input.
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to input the data (I) or allow me to use sample data (S)?");
            var inputMethod = Console.ReadLine();

            if(inputMethod.ToUpper().IndexOf("I") >=0) {
                useSampleData = false; 
            }

            // User Sample Data   
            if (useSampleData) {  // test without using the console input
                gradeBook.Add("Bob", new List<double>() { 67.8, 26.3, 33.2, 33.1, 67.2 });
                gradeBook.Add("Dick", new List<double>() { 88.2, 45.2, 100.0, 89.2, 91.5 });
                gradeBook.Add("Jane", new List<double>() { 99.2, 99.5, 93.9, 98.2, 15.0 });
                gradeBook.Add("Samantha", new List<double>() { 62, 89.5, 93.9, 98.2, 95.0 });
                gradeBook.Add("Estefania", new List<double>() { 95.2, 92.5, 92.9, 98.2, 89 });

                TotalStudents = gradeBook.Count();
                TotalGrades = gradeBook["Bob"].Count();

                TotalStudents = 5;
            
            // user will provide their own data.
            } else { 

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of students: ");
                TotalStudents = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of exams: ");
                TotalGrades = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());



                for (int studentId = 0; studentId < TotalStudents; studentId++) {
                    Console.Write("Please enter name of student {0}: ", studentId);
                    var name = Console.ReadLine();
                    gradeBook.Add(name, new List<double>());
                    for (int testId = 0; testId < TotalGrades; testId++) {
                        Console.Write("Please enter exam score {0} for " + 
                        "student {1}: ", testId + 1, name);
                         gradeBook[name].
                         Add(Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));
                    }
                }
            
            }

            // Here we will divide the grade by 10 as an integer division to
            // get just the first digit of the average and then translate
            // to a letter grade.
            foreach (var student in gradeBook) {
                Console.WriteLine("Student " + student.Key + 
             " scored an average of " + student.Value.Average() + ". " + 
              student.Key + " will recieve a(n) " + 
              gradeTranslator[(int)(student.Value.Average() / 10)] + 
                              " in the class.\n");
            }

            Console.Write("\nPress the [ENTER] key to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a student class to hold the information.

```
public class Student
{
  public string ID
  public List<double> TestScores {get;set;}
  // in this case average only has a getter which calculates the average when needed.
  public double Average 
  {
      get
      { 
       if(TestScores != null && TestScores.Count >0)
         {
           double ave = 0;
           foreach(var x in TestScores)//basic average formula.
              ave += x;
           // using linq this could be reduced to "return TestScores.Average()"
           return ave/TestScores.Count;
         }
         return 0; // can't divide by zero.
      }

  }
  public Student(string id)
  {
   ID = id;
   TestScores = new List<double>();
  }

}
```

Now your dictionary collection can keep the information.  To get you started here are a couple ways to access the data.  Definitely not all inclusive.

Adding elements to the dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string,Student> dict = new Dictionary<string,Student>();
Student stud = new Student("Jerry");
dict.Add(stud.ID,stud);
```

Pulling information:

```
string aveScore = dict["Jerry"].Average.ToString("#.00");
Console.Write(aveScore);
```

looping through the dictionary:

```
foreach(var s in dict.Keys)
{
   dict[s].TestScores.Add(50);
}
```

Comment: You can use LINQ and simply do `return TestScores.Average();`.

Comment: Yes, I didn't want to add too much complexity.  Although it would make a good note.

Comment: Isn't that *less* complexity?

Comment: If you know Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is either homework, or you're trying to learn how to use dictionaries, instead of posting code I'll just point you in the right direction.

A `Dictionary` in C# is a collection of Key-Value pairs. The `Key` must be unique while the `Value` doesn't have to be. So if you define a dictionary as follows:

```
Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

It means you've created a collection of pairs, where the `Key` is of type `int`, and `Value` is also of type `int`. So, if you add a couple of items to the dictionary, it's content would look like this:

[image]

At `index = 0`, you have an item with `Key=1`, and `Value=100`.
At `index = 1`, you have an item with `Key=2`, and `Value=200`.

***But, the `Value` of a dictionary doesn't necessarily have to be a single value. It could also be a `Collection` (or a class object, or even another dictionary).***

Since your requirement is to have a list of scores per student, and a dictionary `Value` permits a `Collection`, it looks like using a dictionary is indeed a good idea. But what kind of a dictionary should we use?

Well, there's many to choose from.

One approach is to use a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`. The `string` representing the student name (or an ID), and the `List<int>` representing test scores. So;

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
```

Now you can populate this dictionary with each student's scores. For example:

```
dict.Add("Arthur Dent", new List<int>() { 75, 54, 26 });
dict.Add("Zaphod Beeblebrox", new List<int>() { 12, 13, 7 });
dict.Add("Ford Prefect", new List<int>() { 99, 89, 69 });
```

In your case, you can get the input from user with each student name and scores.

However, like I said, you can also use a class object as a dictionary `Value`, and, in fact, that is a better approach for your problem. The answer by Felix shows how to do this, so I won't go into details. But you essentially want to create a dictionary as follows, assuming your class is `Student`.

```
Dictionary<string, Student> dict = new Dictionary<string, Student>();
```

Then create instances of `Student` based on user input, and add them to the dictionary. An added advantage of using a `Student` class is that you can have all information related to one student in one place, and also have additional helper methods, such as the `Average()` method in Felix's example so your code will be much cleaner and simpler.